# why some package cannot be found when i try to install python-glanceclient?

Tags: cloud, openstack

according to the following output, there is one error which is **Download error: [Errno 110] Connection timed out -- Some packages may not be found!**, why?

```
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/glanceclient/v1/client.py to client.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/glanceclient/v1/legacy_shell.py to legacy_shell.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/glanceclient/v1/image_members.py to image_members.pyc
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying python_glanceclient.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying python_glanceclient.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying python_glanceclient.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying python_glanceclient.egg-info/entry_points.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying python_glanceclient.egg-info/requires.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying python_glanceclient.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
creating dist
creating 'dist/python_glanceclient-0.5.1.13.9004ee4-py2.6.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' to it
removing 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' (and everything under it)
Processing python_glanceclient-0.5.1.13.9004ee4-py2.6.egg
Copying python_glanceclient-0.5.1.13.9004ee4-py2.6.egg to /home/mirror0/os/lib/python2.6/site-packages
Adding python-glanceclient 0.5.1.13.9004ee4 to easy-install.pth file
Installing glance script to /home/mirror0/os/bin

Installed /home/mirror0/os/lib/python2.6/site-packages/python_glanceclient-0.5.1.13.9004ee4-py2.6.egg
Processing dependencies for python-glanceclient==0.5.1.13.9004ee4
Searching for warlock<2
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/warlock/
Download error: [Errno 110] Connection timed out -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'warlock' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
```

**Edit 1**: failed for the second time:(

```
Installed /home/mirror0/os/lib/python2.6/site-packages/python_glanceclient-0.5.1.13.9004ee4-py2.6.egg
Processing dependencies for python-glanceclient==0.5.1.13.9004ee4
Searching for warlock<2
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/warlock/

Download error: [Errno 110] Connection timed out -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'warlock' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for warlock<2
Best match: None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 46, in <module>
    entry_points={'console_scripts': ['glance = glanceclient.shell:main']},
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 975, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 995, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/home/mirror0/os/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/setuptools/command/install.py", line 76, in run
  File "/home/mirror0/os/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/setuptools/command/install.py", line 104, in do_egg_install
  File "/home/mirror0/os/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 211, in run
  File "/home/mirror0/os/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 427, in easy_install
  File "/home/mirror0/os/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 478, in install_item
  File "/home/mirror0/os/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 519, in process_distribution
  File "/home/mirror0/os/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 563, in resolve
  File "/home/mirror0/os/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 799, in best_match
  File "/home/mirror0/os/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 811, in obtain
  File "/home/mirror0/os/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 434, in easy_install
  File "/home/mirror0/os/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/setuptools/package_index.py", line 475, in fetch_distribution
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clone'
```

i can find warlock using `pip` command:

```
(os)mirror0@lab:~/tmp/python-glanceclient$
(os)mirror0@lab:~/tmp/python-glanceclient$ pip search warlock
warlock                   - Python object model built on top of JSON schema
```

links related to warlock:

1. http://pypi.python.org/pypi/warlock/0.3.1
2. http://pypi.python.org/pypi/warlock/0.0.1
3. http://pypi.python.org/pypi/warlock/0.5.0

Answer (score 0):

[Errno 110] Connection timed out

Seems pretty self explanatory.  Your build environment was unable to query pypi, because when it attempted to connect to their web service it timed out and did not complete it's query, issuing instead an exit error code.